# Conflict jQuery Tabs

Tags: conflict, jquery

I am using following script for tab slides on my magento store. It looks like it is causing jQuery conflict. I tried using `jQuery.noConflict()` but it didnt help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var current = 0;
            $('tabs').firstDescendant().className += ' active-tab';
            var active_tab = $('tabs').firstDescendant().firstDescendant().firstDescendant();
            var motion = false;
            function move_to(to, el){    
               if (!motion) {
                el.parentNode.parentNode.className += ' active-tab';
                if (active_tab) {
                active_tab.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'corner-left-top';
                }
                active_tab = el;    
                move = (current - to)*690;
                new Effect.Move($('tabber'), { x: move, beforeStart:function(){ motion = true;},afterFinish:function(){motion = false;}});
                current = to;
               }
            }        
        </script>
```

Here is the PHP code for the script:

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
    <?php $tabs = 0; ?>
    <?php if ($_description = $this->getChildHtml('description')):  ?>
    <div id="width-tab" class="corner-left-top">
        <div class="corner-right-top" >
            <div class="border-top" onclick="move_to(<?php echo $tabs; $tabs++;?>, this)">
                <h3 style="color:#000;"><?php echo strtoupper($this->__('Overview')); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <?php endif;?>
    <div id="width-tab-2" class="corner-left-top">
        <div class="corner-right-top">
            <div class="border-top" onclick="move_to(<?php echo $tabs; $tabs++;?>, this)">
                <h3 ><?php echo strtoupper($this->__('Specification')); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php  if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
        <div id="width-tab-3" class="corner-left-top">
            <div class="corner-right-top">
                <div class="border-top" onclick="move_to(<?php echo $tabs; $tabs++;?>, this)">
                    <h3><?php echo strtoupper($this->__('Buy')); ?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?><br class="clear-block" />
```

```
<ul id="tabber">
    <li id="container_1" class="tabs-list">Product Description</li>
    <li id="container_2" class="tabs-list">Product Specifications</li>                                      
    <li id="container_3" class="tabs-list">Add to Cart button</li>
</ul>
```

**Issue:**
The id container_3 contains a "Add to Cart" button `<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>` which wont work.

Please Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are 'tabs' and 'tabber' class names or custom HTML tags? If they are classes, use $('.tabs') etc

Comment: Hi @Gerard Sexton, I have added the php code that I am using to show the tabs. Thanks

Comment: So `tabber` is an ID, so please use `$("#tabber")` to select it. I cant seem to find `tabs` anywhere. Is that code selecting anything? Have you gone through it with your debug tools? You do have many tabs-something; If this is what you are after, maybe you could use two classes, ie `<div class="tabs content" ... ></div>` and select them with `$(".tabs.content")`

Comment: Hi, @Gerard Sexton Sorry, I forgot to add the other part of the HTML which I have added now.

Answer (score 3):

`firstDescendant()` is not a jQuery method. That seems from the good ol' Prototype. I think you got some tutorials or something mixed up.

Also, you need to run your script on [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) unless it's embedded after the markup, but in production you'd separate these files anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, try setting move to be a local variable (`var move...`) and second, I'm pretty sure that there is no `firstDescendant` method, unless you're using your own custom script. Regardless, try using `$("tabs").children().first()` instead, as that custom script could be causing the conflict.

EDIT 1:

change your code to wrap whatever you can in a $(document).ready() - this will ensure that all of your dynamically and subsequently added elements are included in the collections populated by using the jQuery selectors. Also set any selectors used multiple times to variables to improve efficiency. Code:

```
var current = 0;
var motion = false;
var active_tab;

function move_to(to, el) { ..... }

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $tabs = $("tabs");
    $tabs......
    active_tab = .....
    /* note that I stopped coding here because I think that you may have 
       gone in the wrong direction for a few of these lines*/
});
```

EDIT 2:

remove the onclick event handler from the HTML element for the add to cart button and move it to the $(document).ready() handler in jQuery (let's try to keep all the script in the same place - at least for now):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".btn-cart").click(function () {
       //assuming the id of the form is productAddToCartForm and the form data is
       //already filled out:
       $("#productAddToCartForm").submit()
    });
});
```

Comment: oh, I almost forgot, unless you are really, Really, REALLY sure what you're doing avoid `noConflict()` at all costs. Ironically enough, I have seen `noConflict()` used many times, have seen it cause issues in nearly all of those implementations and have yet to see it actually successfully prevent conflict. :)

Comment: Hi @Zachary Kniebel Thanks for the reply. I am very new to JS and jQuery world. I have added the php code that I am using for the script.

Comment: soooo although PHP was actually my first web development language I haven't worked with it all that much over the last few years. Let me just make sure I am understanding what is happening before I dive into the JS/jQuery with you. I'm only going to worry about the tabber section because that's really what we are dealing with: basically you have an array of objects that you are trying to display in their own separate tabs. you're displaying information from that object instance on each tab. Correct?

Comment: in other words, your PHP code is used to render the data into a list of elements and then you are simply taking the rendered HTML and styling it into tabs. correct? (I'm just making sure I am reading the PHP right)

Comment: P.S. each time I see something that should be changed/added/removed I will put it in an edit on my original response

Comment: Hi @Zachary, Yes, I have removed all the PHP code. The only issue is that the Add to Cart button which is inside the tab is not working. I can't click it anymore.

Comment: okay, do you have a publicly available development site that I can visit to see the actual issue? (I understand if you don't and we can try to edit this without)

Comment: H @Zachary, I tried you to send the url but I couldn't find a PM option. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14576/discussion-between-flourishdna-and-zachary-kniebel)

Answer (score 1):

If you're having a conflict with Prototype because of the `$` symbol, you can solve this by wrapping your jQuery logic in this:

```
(function($) {
    // jQuery logic here
})(jQuery);
```